# How can I add an object to an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript object that came back from an Entity Framework 5 get from a SQL Server database.

```
var a =
 {
  "questionId":14,
  "questionStatusId":1,
  "answers":null
 }

var b =
 {
  "questionId":15,
  "questionStatusId":1,
  "answers":[
   {"answerId":34,"correct":true,"response":false,"text":"5","image":null,"questionId":15},
   {"answerId":35,"correct":false,"response":false,"text":"50","image":null,"questionId":15}]
 }
```

I would like to add an empty answer object and then send back to the server with a PUT.

How can I add an answer object to variable a and to variable b ?

Comment: `a.answers = [{}]`, `b.answers.push({})`?

Comment: What do you mean by "an empty answer object" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
var newAnswer = {"answerId":0,"correct":false,"response":false,"text":"","image":null,"questionId":0};
b.answers.push(newAnswer);
```

is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
var answer=[];
a.push( { "answer":answer } );
b.push( { "answer":answer } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add properties o objects at runtime in JavaScript. For example

```
var a = { f : 10, g : 20 };
a.h = 30;
```

Similarly, just add the answers property to your a & b with blank objects.

```
a.answer = []; // Empty non null array
b.answer = []; // "
```